# Is there a way to hide account in Gmail?

Tags: sync, gmail, accounts

I use two accounts​ for email, one for contacts. I see all 3 in Gmail app, but only want to see 2. Is there a way to only see my email accounts as choices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Gmail support, accomplishing this without explicity removing it from device is not possible:

> To remove the Gmail account only from the Gmail App isn't possible. If
>   you do not want that account to be available in the Gmail App, the
>   only way to do that is to remove it from your phone's device settings.

Ref:

[Gmail Help Forum: Hide/remove a Google Account ONLY within the Gmail app](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/4i_KqJQFXkw;context-place=forum/gmail)

Answer (score 0):

If your device has xposed framework, you can use xprivacy to hide any account to specific applications, there is no other way for hiding from official gmail Android client.